# Citrix receiver suddenly missing on pc - Win7/Xenapp

Tags: xenapp, citrix

I am having a bit of an issue.
For some reason, citrix receiver is being uninstalled from my users computers without them doing anything?
That is to say, a user is working with a xenapp published application all day, powers off the computer, and when they return the next day the receiver is gone and has to be reinstalled?.
It seems random to me, which users are affected. It users from different sites, different countries even.

I have checked to see if there are any gpo's trying to uninstall/update the receiver but none that I can find.

I have a feeling that it might be the latest windows updates that is to blame, but again, I have no proof at all.

The users are using Windows7 and xenapp 4.5 and 6

all in all I would like to know.
1 - Have any of you had this kind of issue, and what dod you do to fix it?
2 - Is there any place I can check what is going on, why or how the receiver is being uninstalled?

If you feel that you need more info, the please let me know.

Best regards
Dennis